# Loop time execution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

Lets consider the following snippet as example:

```js
var len = 1000000,
    testArr = []

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        testArr.push(i+1)
    }

    function mprofile(name, subject, object) {
        var start = new Date().getTime(),
            result = subject(object),
            end = new Date().getTime() - start
        console.log(name)
        console.log('Result: ' + result)
        console.log(end)
    }

    var length = testArr.length,
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        cnt = 0

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cnt += testArr[i]
    }

    console.log('Regular loop:')
    console.log('Result: ' + cnt)
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);

    start = new Date().getTime()
    cnt = i = 0
    for (i = length; i--; ) {
        cnt += testArr[i]
    }

    console.log('Reversered loop')
    console.log('Result: ' + cnt)
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);

    start = new Date().getTime()
    cnt = i = 0
    var startAt = length%8,
        iterations = Math.floor((length+7) / 8)

    do {
        switch (startAt) {
            case 0: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 7: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 6: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 5: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 4: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 3: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 2: cnt += testArr[i++]
            case 1: cnt += testArr[i++]
        }
        startAt = 0
    } while(--iterations)

    console.log('Duffs device')
    console.log('Result: ' + cnt)
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);

    start = new Date().getTime()
    cnt = i = 0
    iterations = Math.floor((length+7) / 8)

    switch (length % 8) {
        case 0: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 7: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 6: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 5: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 4: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 3: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 2: cnt += testArr[i++]
        case 1: cnt += testArr[i++]
    }

    while(--iterations) {
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
        cnt += testArr[i++]
    }

    console.log('Optimized Duffs device')
    console.log('Result: ' + cnt)
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);


    mprofile(
        'Profiled regular loop',
        function(arr) {
            var cnt = 0,
                length = arr.length
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                cnt += testArr[i]
            }
            return cnt
        },
        testArr
    )

    mprofile(
        'Profiled reversed loop',
        function(arr) {
            var cnt = 0,
                length = arr.length
            for (i = length; i--; ) {
                cnt += testArr[i]
            }
            return cnt
        },
        testArr
    )

    mprofile(
        'Profiled Duffs device',
        function(arr) {
            var cnt = i = 0,
                length = arr.length,
                startAt = length%8,
                iterations = Math.floor((length+7) / 8)

            do {
                switch (startAt) {
                    case 0: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 7: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 6: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 5: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 4: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 3: cnt+ = arr[i++]                     
                       case 2: cnt += arr[i++]
                    case 1: cnt += arr[i++]
                }
                startAt = 0
            } while(--iterations)
            return cnt
        },
        testArr
    )

    mprofile(
        'Profiled optimized Duffs device',
        function(arr) {
            var cnt = i = 0,
                length = arr.length,
                iterations = Math.floor((length+7) / 8)

            switch (length % 8) {
                case 0: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 7: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 6: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 5: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 4: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 3: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 2: cnt += arr[i++]
                case 1: cnt += arr[i++]
            }

            while(--iterations) {
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
                cnt += arr[i++]
            }
            return cnt
        },
        testArr
    )
```

There is a difference between reported execution time from plain loops vs loops executed inside of callbacks. Furtermore there is difference in execution time if you run it inside of **script tag in head** vs execute it in **developer console** as shown in this images:

1. Result from script tag: [image: result from script tag]
2. Result from console (Firefox): [image: result from console tool in Firefox]

Can anyone explain why this is happening or provide links to any resource where I can find out any information related to this. Also would appreciate if browser differences would be covered in response or document you will link.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Could you at least explain what this does, what the difference is, and why there shouldn't be any difference? All I see is iterating a million times, adding stuff etc, and one browser being more efficient than the other, which is not very suprising, those numbers are millisecond, and it would be astonishing if two different browsers managed to use the exact same time

Comment: It is called **loop optimization**. You should see several different techniques of handling looping over arrays. **The question is about difference in executing same algorithm in global scope vs executing it as a callback**. Why there **must not** be difference in execution time is simple enough because the logic is the same. And btw this is example from same browser which is Firefox.

Comment: Note that generally Duff's device is not very useful in most interpreted languages. It's usefulness comes form the fact that in assembly/machine language, a label doesn't exist in the executable code (it exists only for the compiler to generate code) therefore a series of uninterrupted labels look no different from a sequence of instructions. Duff's device basically hacks at C's implementation of the switch statement that usually compile down to a jump table. In interpreted languages, this may not be the case.

Comment: So both those results are from the console, but the latter one is from running the code directly in the console, and former from running the code from a HTML file, and you're wondering why they aren't the same ?

Comment: @slebetman Yes you are correct, but as shown in the pic it actually provides small increase in productivity. The question is why there is a big difference between the way algorithms got executed and the end time. Cause there is no change in logic. For example why the time spend looping is less once you invoke same algorithm from within callback as opposed to global scope.

Comment: @adeneo yes this is second part of the question. The first one is: why the way you invoke same logic is also affects execution time. For example in pic1 you can see that invoking same logic from within callback mprofile yields faster execution then from just using global scope.

Comment: So you're also asking why it would take longer to look up a variable in a higher scope, like a global over a local? If you divide the difference in milliseconds by a million runs, the difference is almost immeasurable, and is probably just the added overhead of looking further up the chain. The console also has overhead when running code, it does after all do more stuff.

Comment: @adeneo check the snippet please, there is no call to variable which couldn't be resolved in a scope of current ActivationObject. That means there will be no lookup performed in a higher scope.

Comment: this might be because when you inject code it runs on its own vm. but when you add a script it is running on the main thread

Comment: @udnisap thank you that may explains the difference between scrip element and developer console. Is there anything specific about optimization of closures in JS that makes them run faster then just running code in global scope?

Comment: I see closure as a way of arranging the code better with modularization, encapsulation. There can be instances where closure is speed bcz `this` in global is the global `window` object where are in a closure mostly it is the closure. this will definitely have performance gains when you try to iterate through `this`. there can also be performance gain in global approach because the prototype chain is shallow say for example when you try to access non existing property from an object. other than things like that I dont think there will be performance gains using closure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `performance.now()` is the best option to measure performance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

- end time calculation is wrong. in your `mprofile` function you calculate a diff BEFORE calling the first `console.log`, in ordinary code - AFTER the second one. so, in one case you include interaction with console into your measurement, in other - not
- also, the whole example is a bit incorrect. you should create a functions like `loop`, `reverseLoop`, etc. and measure time before/after calling them. then you should measure time for **the same functions** in callbacks. and you should run each case at least 10-times and check avg times.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Chrome `console.time()` is pretty useful.
e.g:

```
console.time('myTime1')
console.timeEnd('myTime1') //myTime1: 5047.492ms
```

Comment: I also tried this approach. It still reports same behavior. Difference is it is a bit more precise then using new **new Date().getTime()**

Comment: Also works in firefox and IE11 and Edge and Opera and Safari - so, pretty much any useful browser has it